# Trying to select only top level li items and exclude sub level drop down ones in a a nav

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm editing CSS on a wordpress site and struggling with a selector. Below is some of the nav. I would like to apply to following styling to only the top level `<li>`s not the ones in nested drop downs. But everything I apply seems to affect the drop down menu too.

Here is the styling that I'd like to apply:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background: orange;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

But when I do it affects the nested drop down menu li items too. What selector should I use? Here is the site: http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/

```
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li ><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-57"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=57">Clear Outs &#038; Offers</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor current_page_parent"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=8">Flooring</a>
           <ul class='children'>
             <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=19">Chestnut</a></li>
             <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=15">Douglas Fir</a></li>
             <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=12">Heart Pine</a></li>
             <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=17">Maple</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-10 current_page_item"><a href="http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/?page_id=10">Oak</a></li>
           </ul>
```

I tried a few things including:
`.dropdown ul > li:hover` { // note the right arrow. Shouldn't that mean only first generation children of .dropdown ul?

Also tried this:

```
.dropdown > ul > li:hover // same logic but still impacts the sub menu?
```

Comment: Have you tried? `.dropdown > ul li:hover`

Comment: As you are targeting the li on hover it will cover the child ul too (unless this is positioned absolutely and outside of the parent li) but to answer the first part `.dropdown ul > li:hover` covers all uls found within .dropdown (which includes the .children and their lis)

Comment: @Evan just tried it. No luck. I'm struggling on this one

Comment: @Doug Firr maybe you can create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: @Doug Strange - well, since you have a class available, you could take advantage of `.dropdown .main-nav > li:hover { background: #FFA500; }`

Comment: @Pete I think that this is the problem, the ul is nested within the li and since it's a wordpress it's more tricky to change

Answer (score 0):

The unordered list items or `<li>`s in your second level of dropdown are children of the list above them, or to put it another way, they are children of the list in which they are contained. It is because of this that they inherit the style of their parents. One way (not necessarily the best), but the one I would use is to style the parent list in the way you want and then create another rule that applies only to the children, thereby overriding the first rule for the parents. The running order is important here. The second rule, the one that targets the children must come after the one that targets the parents in your stylesheet. The second rule will only override the first if it comes later in the stylesheet.

Style for parents:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background: orange;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Style for children that overrides the style you have set for the parent:

```
.dropdown ul li li:hover {
    background: black; /* Or whatever your default color is*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

NEW!

Anchor tags!

The `<a>` anchor tags contained inside your `<li>` s are also children of the parent list and so inherit there opacity state. This means you need to override style set them too!

```
.dropdown ul li li a:hover { 
    background: black; /* Or whatever your default color is*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Another, tidier way to approach this may be to style the anchor tags for opacity and colour and not the list tags. The sub lists are children of the parent list, but not the parent anchor tags, so rules set to the top level anchors won't be passed down the hierarchy. However in order to see the styles effect the anchors in the way you want you will also need to set their display type to inline-block. So:

```
.dropdown  a { 
    display:inline-block; /* will make all your navigations anchors inline-block*/
    /*Style all your navigation links in here, rather than styling their parent li's*/
    background:white; /*or whatever*/
}


.dropdown ul li a:hover {
    background: orange; /* Or whatever your default color is*/
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: Hi Doug. I've just made an edit to my answer. It relates to the order in which you list your rules in your stylesheet. Try putting your rules in the order they are listed above in at the very end of your stylesheet. It is possible you have another pesky rule that is conflicting with your stated intentions elsewhere in your stylesheet. Rules set at the very end take precedence over everything.

Comment: Hm. Yes I listed at the end of the stylesheet in that order. Must be a pesky rule somewhere

Comment: Nope again! Take a look, just added your latest update: http://gcameron8977.webfactional.com/

Comment: but moleytv's idea is correct - the only way to do it